# XI2. How to ignore events of modifier keys?

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I'm trying to fix [xneur](https://github.com/yrHeTaTeJlb/xneur-devel) keyboard switcher. Its author tried to add XI2 support, but broke input in the applications that use only XI2(google chrome for example).

And I'm stuck with modifiers filtering. There is the [following code](https://github.com/yrHeTaTeJlb/xneur-devel/blob/892acf38f9a321e4e54179b6a240a6f2a63ffe88/xneur/lib/main/utils.c#L176):

```
// Grab all keys...
if (has_x_input_extension) {
    XIEventMask mask;
    mask.deviceid = XIAllDevices;
    mask.mask_len = XIMaskLen(XI_KeyPress)+
                    XIMaskLen(XI_KeyRelease);
    mask.mask = (void *)calloc(mask.mask_len, sizeof(char));
    XISetMask(mask.mask, XI_KeyPress);
    XISetMask(mask.mask, XI_KeyRelease);
    XISelectEvents(main_window->display, DefaultRootWindow(main_window->display), &mask, 1);
    free(mask.mask);
}
else {
    XGrabKey(main_window->display, AnyKey, AnyModifier, window, FALSE, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);
    // ...without ModKeys.
    grab_modifier_keys(window, FALSE);
}
```

`grab_modifier_keys` ungrabs key modifiers. And I don't know how to do the same with XI2(`if` branch).

---

I think it's possible to ignore those events in the [event handling loop](https://github.com/yrHeTaTeJlb/xneur-devel/blob/master/xneur/lib/main/program.c#L499). Something like this:

```
int is_modifier (XEvent *event)
{ 
    /* ??? */
}

while (1) {
    XEvent event;
    XNextEvent(display, &event);
    if (is_modifier(event)) {
        continue;
    } 
}
```

But I don't know how to implement `is_modifier` function.

I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a perfect solution, but here is an implementation of `is_modifier` I came up with:

```
Bool is_modifier(KeySym key_sym)
{
    XModifierKeymap *modmap = XGetModifierMapping(main_window->display);
    if (modmap == NULL) {
        return False;
    }

    KeyCode key_code = XKeysymToKeycode(main_window->display, key_sym);

    int size = modmap->max_keypermod * 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        if (key_code == modmap->modifiermap[i]) {
            return True;
        }
    }

    XFreeModifiermap(modmap);

    return False;
}
```